# The programming languages A, B and C

Tags: word-order

Is it correct if I write something like

> He has knowledge of the programming languages A, B and C

Or does it necessarily have to be like

> He has knowledge of the A, B and C programming languages

Comment: He has knowledge of the languages japanese, english and hindi vs he has knowledge of the Japanese, English and Hindi language. Which seems proper to you?

Comment: Isn't it apparent that A - C are programming languages?

Comment: To have knowledge of something could mean he’s just heard about them.  If you mean he knows the languages (he is capable of sitting down and writing a program in them with minimal references) then just say that he ***knows*** A, B, and C.  I’ve never heard of A though ;-)  (Although Wikipedia says A+ and A++ do exist)

Comment: So it is wrong. But would it be considered to be completely wrong? Thank you all for your help. @Jim sorry for that :), I just replaced the real names with A B C in the question formulation :)

Comment: @PhantomR - No it’s not completely wrong, just not precise as it could be.  (And I understood your letter substitutions- I just found it amusing...)

Comment: Is this a resume? To say 'knowledge of' is a bit too mild, whereas 'experienced in A, B, and C' is the standard pronouncement for a seasoned software developer.

Comment: @Jim Thank you for your help, I see now what you meant about the "with knowledge of" construct and I'll try to replace it :D. It really is interesting that there actually are languages with (almost) those names.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, it's for something like that :). Well, I am just a student, so I am not experienced, but do you think it would be acceptable if I said like "able to program in the A, B and C languages"?

Comment: Saying _able_ is too humble. I would say 'Program in A, B, and C.' Not languages, just ' ... in Java, C++, and Ruby.'

Comment: @YosefBaskin I started like "[..] Student, able to program .." . Would it be better if I wrote like "Student, familiar with A, B, and C"? I can't figure out how I'd integrate 'Program in A, B, and C' :)

Comment: Both sentences are fine. They just emphasize differently.

Comment: Even if you wrote a total of three programs, you can write "Student, **programming** in A, B, and C." If you are programming in those languages, we already know that they are programming languages. If you say that the programming languages are programming languages, you are saying the 'Earth planet.' Not needed.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Oh... I think I somehow see what you meant. Thank you :)

Comment: Well I've heard of B and used C, but I've never heard of A.

Answer (score 0):

Correct English, in my opinion, but “have knowledge of a programming language” sounds rather strange and stilted. I suggest, instead, the simple and unambiguous:

> “He can program in A, B and C.”

As has been commented, it’s obvious that they are programming languages in this sentence, so there is no need to say so.